# i want parted my used hard disk

Tags: gparted

can i parted my used hard disk?

i have is report with this command: `sudo fdisk -l`

`Dispositivo Inicio  Comienzo     Final  Sectores Tamaño Id Tipo
/dev/sda1   *           2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2            1052670 976771071 975718402 465.3G  5 Extendida
/dev/sda5          964397056 976771071  12374016   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6            1052672 964397055 963344384 459.4G 83 Linux`

La partición 2 no empieza en el límite del sector físico.
Las entradas de la tabla de particiones no están en el orden del disco.

can i not resize my disk, why?[image]

Comment: You cannot resize the partition you have booted from in Linux. It is like trying to change a tire of your car while driving. Boot from a Live USB also known as installation USB and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**. Then use gparted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that your cannot partition your hard-drive because it is active. Therefore, your hard-disk need to be in an inactive state. I recommend you to install Gparted-live on an external drive, e.g. on a USB stick. It will help you to partition your hard-disk. For more information and instructions, see: 
https://gparted.org/livecd.php

There are also installation instructions.